# Select all parents having a child with specific property

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

Consider the following pseudo tables:

```
Parent(id)
Child(id, parent_id, property)
```

How can I select all parents having a child where property has a specific value in PostgreSQL?

Comment: What have you tried? Include your SQL code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+recursive-query

Comment: select p.* from parent p join child c on p.id=c.parent_id where c.property='change_me' group by p.id ;   If you need parents where only one child have that property then use having(cout(id)) =1;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select p.*
from parent p
where exists (select 1
              from child c
              where c.parent_id = p.id and c.property = ?
             );
```